# Activated SSL on magento , but now JS resources doesn't load

Tags: magento2, ssl

I'm using magento 2.0.7, and I've activated the SSL , and now when I go on the website , it loads with https, but it doesn't load anymore the js resources.

Comment: Try `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: already did that , but still doesn't load..